# HttpClient.GetAsync Throws 413 Request Entity Too Large

Tags: c#, azure-functions, httpclient, .net-8.0, http-status-code-413

I have a .NET 8 C# Azure Functions app. It calls a third party vendor API, which returns a very large JSON. Most of the times the following code works, but only sometimes it throws 413 Request Entity Too Large error. When it throws an error in my code, the same request works perfectly fine in Postman.

```
public async Task<MyLargeObject> GetMyLargeObjectAsync(string unique_id)
{
    MyLargeObject myLargeObject = new MyLargeObject();

    try
    {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient()
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("*/*"));
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.UserAgent.ParseAdd("MyApp/1.0.0");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", _token);

        var response = await client.GetAsync(_vendorEndPointURL + unique_id);

        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode(); // This line throws exception when response JSON is very large
        if (response.Content != null)
        {
            HttpContent content = response.Content;
            string result = content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            myLargeObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyLargeObject>(result);

        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _logger.LogError(ex, $"Error getting MyLargeObject from Vendor API. Unique ID: {unique_id}");
        throw;

    }
    return myLargeObject;
}
```

I even added the following in Program.cs, but still no joy:

```
services.Configure<KestrelServerOptions>(options =>
{
    options.Limits.MaxRequestBodySize = long.MaxValue;
    options.Limits.MaxResponseBufferSize = long.MaxValue;
}); 
services.Configure<IISServerOptions>(options =>
{
    options.MaxRequestBodySize = long.MaxValue; 
});
```

Comment: _"When it throws an error in my code, the same request works perfectly fine in Postman."_ - you mean when you query the 3rd party API with the same data?

Comment: @GuruStron Yes that’s correct

Comment: In WebApis you also need to add a file "web.config" to your project with the request filtering value ie. <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="2073741824" />. Not sure you can do this with Azure functions tho but maybe worth a try.

Comment: @mattsharp Your suggestion does not apply on Azure Functions. If you've done it or have a code example then please post here.

Comment: Maybe try client.MaxResponseContentBufferSize = 2073741824; before you send the request

Comment: Does the same happen if you try using `HttpClient` outside of the context of Azure Functions. Shown settings should not affect how the http client works.

Comment: Does the 3rd party api support gzip encoding? you may try to request a gzipped encoded response. This will drastically reduce the payload size.

Comment: @mattsharp setting client.MaxResponseContentBufferSize was a good suggestion, but it did not work. Same error. I haven’t tried it in outside Azure Functions yet. But even if works outside Azure Functions, it’s still a show stopper, because AF is a requirement because of several different ways it can be triggered.

Comment: @MarcoMerola Trying gzipped encoded response is a good suggestion. I know the API supports is because that’s how Postman is also getting the response. If you’ve implemented it, then an example code snippet would be very helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Instantiating HTTPClient like this solved the problem:

```
                HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler() { AutomaticDecompression = System.Net.DecompressionMethods.GZip | System.Net.DecompressionMethods.Deflate | System.Net.DecompressionMethods.Brotli };
                HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler);
```

Comment: You shouldn't be using the HttpClient this way. This is even more problematic in Azure functions. Please read: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/errors-diagnostics/sdk-rules/azf0002
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/implement-resilient-applications/use-httpclientfactory-to-implement-resilient-http-requests